# react-native packager returns 404 for everything

Tags: react-native

So I started looking at React-Native just recently (2 days ago).  I have deployed to an apk before and debugged on simulator in eclipse,
but I do NOT understand how the application is served/pushed/hosted.

I have tried a few different examples of react-native open source projects with no luck.  I can get the packager running.  Build finishes. Graph etc. Done.  If I open a web browser on the PC and point to http://localhost:8081/anypage i get CANNOT get/ anypage (404) all the time.
So now what?

The projects have components (screens).  I can't seem to GET to any of them.

I was able to get an android emulator running (api23arm) and i can open a BROWSER on it.  What medium is the app ran on in the actual mobile device (BROWSER?)

If it's BROWSER, then I have tried pointing to http://packagerserver_ip:8081/index.android.bundle?blah-blah and it packages something and it sends it as TEXT to the browser on the emulator.  Is that normal?  Why is it TEXT?  How can i view the compiled version of the source code instead of the raw source in the browser?  Hopefully I am just missing something simple here and I'm not supposed to connect to the project that way maybe?  Is the project supposed to be hosted on that 8081 like a web server (html/javascript/css compiled)?
I have no android device with an operating system > 4.1 so I can't debug with react-native it seems on my old phone.

I have tried these calls from both my PC browser and the emulator browser.

When testing from PC browser, what does the url look like to test a single page in the project? Let's say myfirstpage. (http://localhost:8081/myfirstpage?)

Please help!!! This SEEMED to look simple to use but has become very frustrating to say the least.

EDIT:
As suggested, I have no code to show because it happens the same on all projects.  I tried using this: https://github.com/caioariede/uber-react for starters and I can't even get an error other than 404 trying to open a page in a browser to packager:8081.  If I saw ANY error other than that related to logic issue somewhere in the app I would be ecstatic, but I ONLY see 404's.

Comment: Share code or it didn't happen. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: https://github.com/caioariede/uber-react ... i dont have any specific code as the problem is not related to code as far as i can tell.  I can try ANY project on the internet and get 404 for the pages from my browser after packager is running.  So I figure it is a basic understanding issue of VIEWING the project somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to internet through a proxy ? If yes then you need to exclude those proxies for localhost.